# Ordering child pages underneath parent pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, menu

I am trying to create a database driven menu but I am unsure how to arrange my child pages underneath my parent pages with the way I have implemented my code.

SQL call:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Get all of the pages on the website
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DataTable GetAllWebsitePages()
    {
        DataTable returnVal = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["websiteContent"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            string SQL = "SELECT * FROM Website_Pages";
            using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlCon))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm))
                {
                    dataAdapter.Fill(returnVal);
                }
            }
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```

C#:

```
private void refreshPages()
{
    lvPages.DataSource = CMS.WebsitePages.Pages.GetAllWebsitePages();
    lvPages.DataBind();
}
```

ASP.NET:

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTitle" CssClass="cmsTitle"><%#Eval("Website_Page_Name")%></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnEdit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Website_Page_ID")%>'
                        CommandName="editPage" ImageUrl="../../images/NTU-CMS-Edit.png" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnDelete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Website_Page_ID")%>'
                        CommandName="deletePage" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this page?');"
                        ImageUrl="../../images/NTU-CMS-Delete.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

In the database, all of my pages have an ID and the child pages have a parent ID. E.g Our History has a parent page of 2, which is About Us.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please post some sample data and how you would like it to appear on your page.

Comment: For example, there are pages (ID 1) Home, (ID 2) About, (ID 3) Placements and (ID 4) Contact Us. I want to add a child page to About called Our History, which will have an ID of 5 and a parent ID of 2. I need a vertical list with Our History to appear below About, which I can then indent with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an old technique for grouped data like that - first thing is to get your SQL to output something like this...

```
Parent     Child
---------- ----------
Home       Home
Products   Products
Products   Widget
Products   Midget
Products   Fidget
About Us   About Us
About Us   History
About Us   Contact Us
```

Then you loop through that and consume each row to build your menu... the following is pseudo-code...

```
String currentGroup = "";
MenuItem currentParentMenuItem = null;
foreach(DBRow r in results) {
  if (currentGroup != r.Group) {
      //create a new group
      currentGroup = r.Group;

      //add that group as a "Parent" item
      //Store the Parent in a MenuItem so we can add the children next time through
      currentParentMenuItem = newParentWeCreatedAbove;
  } else {
      //add the current row as a child to the current Parent menu group
      currentParentMenuItem.AddChild(r.Child);
  }
}
```

Basically that is: every time the group name changes, we create a new group and add all children to that group until the group name changes again.